# Unable to pull ALL documents from MongoDB collection in jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, mongodb-query

Unable to pull all the documents from **MongoDB** collection using **Jmeter JSR233** sampler.

I’m trying to pull all the documents from MongoDB collection to jmeter to pass it as a test case for my performance test execution.
The below works -

```
myDoc = collection.find(eq("ABCValue", "ABC")).first();
log.info myDoc.toJson();

collection.find(...query...).last(); also works.
```

I’m able to pull the first and last value from MongoDB collection for that query.  However unable to pull all the documents from the collection when I try to use the following -

```
myDoc = collection.find();
log.info myDoc.toJson();
```

This does not work only in Jmeter.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To print **all documents** returned from `find()`, you need to [iterate](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) over the documents returned

```
for (Document cur : collection.find()) {
     log.info cur.toJson();
}
```

> The `find()` method returns a `FindIterable()` instance that provides a fluent interface for chaining other methods.